# Setting Proxy in R and windows for Leaflet Package

Tags: r, windows, proxy, leaflet

I usually don't have trouble downloading packages and using them currently in my office but I do have trouble accessing some API's and using Leaflet (map does not render)

these things work while I am off the network but I wish to use my works proxy which I have the IP and user/pass but Can't get it to work on Windows.

So far I have tried the following with no success:

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://user@ip:8080/")
Sys.getenv("http_proxy")
```

This returns the proxy but does not allow leaflet maps to render still.

I managed to get this proxy to work in Python when installing packages with the following in the Terminal:

```
pip install mpld3 --proxy=http://user@ip:8080
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

setInternet2(FALSE)

Comment: Thanks but does not help, Tried both TRUE and FALSE values.